# JQuery Not working after updating NUNIT to 3.7

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, bdd

I have used to find an element using jQuery select0r.
This is how am trying to find out the element.

```
var linkDom = new DomElement(DomElementType.JQuerySelector, string.Format("{0} a:icontains(\"{1}\")", tableDataElement.AttributeValue, columnName));
```

I am using:

```
Selenium.WebDriver.Extensions.3.0.1 and \Selenium.WebDriver.3.6.0.
```

Till updating the version to 3.7 NUnit console everything was fine.
now entire suite is very slow and elements are not picking using jquery.

Does anyone have an idea about this?